# Joining 2 selects results - whilst setting multiple allias

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Hi i am very new to this so sorry i if do not explain this well.

I have 2 tables (delegate and module) both with column names such as "no" and "name" which are repeated

What I am trying to acheive is get a result of the 4 tables .

Heres my coding :

```
SELECT no AS del_no, name AS del_name
 FROM delegate

Union ALL

 SELECT code AS module_code, name AS module_name
 FROM module;
```

My result is two columns with everything from module stacked underneath
but what i really want is 4 colums from 2 different tables.

I am unable to change the column names as this is in my requirements.

Comment: What is the relation between your `Delegate` and `Module` tables?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/k9cojk/8

Comment: Your title is wrong I think, you are not joining here you are unioning.

Comment: :/ i am quite new to this sorry

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, in the first you combine the results to a shared column like so

```
select t, shared, name from
(
  SELECT 1 as ordering, 'del_no' as t, no AS shared, name FROM delegate
  Union ALL
  SELECT 2 as ordering, 'module' as t, code AS shared, name FROM module
) sub
order by ordering asc
```

In the second each data type gets it's own column

```
select del_name, module_name, name from
(
  SELECT 1 as ordering, no as del_name, null as module_name, name FROM delegate
  Union ALL
  SELECT 2 as ordering, null as del_name, code as module_name, name FROM module
) sub
order by ordering asc
```

In both cases the key is having a column used just for ordering in the outer query.

Comment: first one works but i get the wrong result , the second one gets

Comment: "unknown colum `t` in field list

Comment: Maybe you should give an example of expected output in your question.

Comment: i still do not have the 4 colulms i am aftfer

Comment: Sorry i did state that at first just not clearly, i am a ameture at this

Comment: @user3254111 -- I still don't know what you want.  You have to give an example of the output you expect, not a picture of what my query returns... *I know* what my query will return.  What I don't know is what the heck you want.  You say 4 columns but you don't say what they are.  There is no way for me to help you if you don't say what you want.